# Can't model in the view in emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am just getting started with ember... I managed to save the data to firebase but can't get it to the client, this is my code:

Route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
     model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('post')
  }
});
```

template:

```
{{#each model}}
    <h2> {{model.title}}</h2>
{{/each}}
```

modeljs:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),

});
```

I did manage to save an item to firebase with a form on my website so the model is sending data to firebase but I am not sure how to get it back to the view?

Comment: The code you have is code that _should_ work.  The issue is most likely with your data e.g. no data being returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template is wrong.

This is the correct one :

```
{{#each model as |item|}}
    <h2> {{item.title}}</h2>
{{/each}}
```